# How do i deploy web service on wildfly 10?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I cannot deploy web service on wildfly 10, but can on wildfly 12. Please tell me what's wrong.

Error show like this:

```
Cannot upload deployment: Unable to parse response with content-type text/html
```

So, I used jdk 1.8

Thank in advance.

Comment: There are many way to deploy an application on wildfly, which are you trying to use?

Comment: @Aaron I tried to deploy on console page. which is wildfly 10 and deploy in eclipse is working (wildfly 12)

Comment: There probably was an error during deployment that the web console fails to show, you should check your server.log

Comment: @Aaron (java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\undertow7857326714886087310upload: There is not enough space on the disk.) The disk is full?

Comment: Yup, looks like it !